# Recursion binary tree print error

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am having some issues while working on this assignment.I am currently trying to power through this. I am able to store and print values, however when I print the values it only prints the first value I entered. Any help would be amazing! I really don't know much about recursion and it kinda makes brain hurt.

```
package lab6;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class node {

    private int value;
    static node root;
    public node leftLink;
    public node rightLink;

    public node(int v) {
        this.value = v;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    static void traverseShow() {
        if (root.leftLink != null) {
            root = root.leftLink;
            traverseShow();
        }
        System.out.println(root.getValue());
        if (root.rightLink != null) {
            root = root.rightLink;
            traverseShow();

        }

        return;
    }

    static void addNode(node n) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = n;
        } else {
            node tmp = root; // save the current root
            if (root.getValue() > n.getValue()) {
                root = root.leftLink;
                addNode(n);
            } else if (root.getValue() < n.getValue()) {
                root = root.rightLink;
                addNode(n);
            }
            root = tmp; // put the root back to its original value
        }
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int val = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean loop = true;
        String command = "";

        while (loop == true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a command:");
            System.out.println("A = insert a new value");
            System.out.println("B = display all values");
            System.out.println("C = exit program");
            command = sc.next();
            if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
                System.out.println("Enter value: ");
                val = sc.nextInt();
                node newNode = new node(val);
                addNode(newNode);
            } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
                traverseShow();
            } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
                sc.close();
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid command! Please try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `node` class shouldn't have a `node root` variable. And definitely shouldn't be static. Also, it is not clear what exactly isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected your code and split it in two classes: Main and Node. Now I tested it and it is working. Your main mistake is that you can't change the root because it is our only reference to access the whole tree. Instead, you will want to tell the child Node to addNode(node n) for you. That's when recursion takes place. The same is valid to method traverseShow(). In fact, debugging is going to help you quite a lot in cases like that.

```
public class Node {

    private int value;
    public Node leftLink;
    public Node rightLink;

    public Node() {

    }

    public Node(int v) {
        this.value = v;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    void addNode(Node n) {

        //node tmp = root; // save the current root
        if (getValue() > n.getValue()) {
            if(leftLink == null){
                leftLink = n;
            }else{
                leftLink.addNode(n);
            }
        } else if (getValue() < n.getValue()) {
            if(rightLink == null){
                rightLink = n;
            }else{
                rightLink.addNode(n);
            }
            //root = root.rightLink;
            //addNode(n);
        }
        //root = tmp; // put the root back to its original value

        return;
    }

    void traverseShow() {
        if (leftLink != null) {
            leftLink.traverseShow();
        }
        System.out.println(getValue());
        if (rightLink != null) {
            rightLink.traverseShow();
        }

        return;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node rootNode = null;
        int val = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean loop = true;
        String command = "";

        while (loop == true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a command:");
            System.out.println("A = insert a new value");
            System.out.println("B = display all values");
            System.out.println("C = exit program");
            command = sc.next();
            if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
                System.out.println("Enter value: ");
                val = sc.nextInt();
                Node newNode = new Node(val);
                if(rootNode == null){
                    rootNode = new Node(val);
                }else{
                    rootNode.addNode(newNode);
                }
            } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
                rootNode.traverseShow();
            } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
                sc.close();
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid command! Please try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```